# Is it possible to forward signed transaction using bitcoind prune mode?

Tags: bitcoin-core, transactions, bitcoind, pruning

**Summary:**
Is it possible to perform `createrawtranscation` , `signrawtransaction` and `sendrawtransaction` rpc call using bitcoin in prune mode?

**Detail :**
I want to implement an API that performs p2p BTC transfer, and for this purpose, I don't want to run a full node in my AWS server as I have to buy extra space for this. I was exploring third-party applications but all of them are out of my budget. So I was curious if I could run prune mode BTC core to perform above mention RPC call?

I would be very thankful if you guys can give some advice as per my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to perform createrawtranscation , signrawtransaction and sendrawtransaction rpc call using bitcoin in prune mode?

Yes

I did the transactions in below link using pruned node:

https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/99679/103136

`rescanblockchain` might be required if you are using any imported addresses in the transactions and it will work only for blocks saved on disk

I had to use [rescanblockchain](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.20.0/rpc/wallet/rescanblockchain/) in this example: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/99112/103136

Comment: it seems you have done that for internal wallet address, what if i want to execute similar process for external address with private key access?

Comment: Then you can use [signrawtransactionwithkey](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.20.0/rpc/rawtransactions/signrawtransactionwithkey/). Example: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/99021/